# Modify every value of specified key in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I've got a database with multiple rows and columns, which are grabbed with PDO.

```
$sql     = "SELECT timestamp FROM table";
$stmt    = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$results = $stmt->execute;
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

One of the database columns is `timestamp` which is a 10 digit unix timestamp. I'd like to convert this server side to a readable format before sending it to the browser.

This is how I'd like it to be formatted, but I know it needs to be done on every row and this is where it trips me up. Possibly a foreach loop?

```
$results['timestamp'] = date('H:i\, l jS \of F Y', $results['timestamp']);
```

Comment: Sounds like a good possibility. Have you tried it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes. It might work with if my query returned a single row, but as it's multiple rows I need to iterate through every one.

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler to do that in the DB directly, since the DB will already be "looping" on the exact same data, saving you having to reloop in client-side code:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H:%i, etc...') FROM table
```

The format codes are documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: do you need the backticks for `timestamp`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: Ok. I thought you needed to escape the reserved words.

Comment: You need, unless they are permitted: `MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them. Examples are those in the following list:

ACTION

BIT

DATE

ENUM

NO

TEXT

TIME

TIMESTAMP`

Comment: That is one suggestion, but I might need to modify other columns. This approach is neat but will only work with the keywords above, such as DATE_FORMAT. A foreach loop will let me modify this timestamp example, and any other variables that need things appended to them/modified before being submitted to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :)

```
array_walk($results, function(&$value) {
    $value['timestamp'] = date('H:i\, l jS \of F Y', $value['timestamp']);
}
```